# How can I access a UserControl from inside a class in App_code?

Tags: c#, app-code

In a ASP.net Website project, I have a class in App_code folder called "abc" and have user control in a folder on root MyControl/Menu.ascx.

Now my question is how can I create an instance of my UserControl inside my "abc" class? because UserControl is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this

```
CustomControl cc = (CustomControl)Page.LoadControl("...");
```

Comment: This is not possible directly, you have to made the "CustomControl" class accessible first.

Thanks for the commen

Comment: Yes do you have public specifier?

Comment: yes i do. Please note that its a "ASP.net Website" type of Project rather than "ASP.Net Project" type of Project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include proper `namespace` of your user control

   `using YourNamespace;`
2. Then Create Instance of uer control

   `UserControlClass userconrtolinstance = new UserControlClass();`

Comment: I have tried this as well please check this below.

namespace MyTheme
{
  public class abc()
  {
   UserControlClass userconrtolinstance = new UserControlClass();
  }
}


i assigned the same namepace to the control as well. Its still not finding it.

Comment: and what is the nampespace you are using in `using block`?

Comment: i created a namespace called "MyTheme" and the control and the class is under the same namespace.